# Google foo.bar hiring challenge skipping work

Tags: python, arrays

This morning I started Google's foo.bar challenge. The quest was comparing 2 lists and returning non-same values.

> For example, given the lists x = [13, 5, 6, 2, 5] and y = [5, 2, 5,
> 13], the function solution(x, y) would return 6 because the list x
> contains the integer 6 and the list y doesn't.

So I wrote this code;

```
x = [13, 5, 6, 2, 5]
y = [5, 2, 5, 13]

list_difference1 = [item for item in x if item not in y]
list_difference2 = [item for item in y if item not in x]


list_difference = list_difference2 + list_difference1
list_difference
```

output: [6]

This is what it looks like in the script;

```
def solution(x, y):
    list_difference1 = [item for item in x if item not in y]
    list_difference2 = [item for item in y if item not in x]

    list_difference = list_difference2 + list_difference1

    return list_difference
```

I can't understand what I have done wrong.

Comment: Why do you think you've done something wrong? Seems that you've gotten the right answer from your toy example there

Comment: Please include the task specification, not just the example.

Comment: My answer is not accepted by the compiler, that is what got me thinking that I was doing wrong. And, an example of the specifications is mentioned in the quote.

Comment: No accepted by the "compiler"? That doesn't sound right. And yes, the example already shows the result type, but the specification text really makes it clear. You can tell by Alex's comment and Timur's answer that they didn't realize the issue, but they likely would've had they seen the specification text (which makes it clear that there's exactly one number difference and that exactly that number shall be returned).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're supposed to return `6`, not `[6]`.

Comment: In case someone is wondering: [google it](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22would+return+6+because+the+list+x+contains+the+integer+6%22) for full specification of the problem.

Comment: Since I thought different elements can be multiple I returned an array but when I simply returned "list_difference[0]" it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets), which are faster than lists:

```
x = [13, 5, 6, 2, 5]
y = [5, 2, 5, 13]

def solution(x, y):
    return list(set(x) ^ set (y))

print(solution(x, y))
# [6]
```

Otherwise, you code seems correct (just not as efficient):

```
def solution2(x, y):
    list_difference1 = [item for item in x if item not in y]
    list_difference2 = [item for item in y if item not in x]
    list_difference = list_difference2 + list_difference1
    return list_difference

print(solution2(x, y))
# [6]
```

Comment: I actually tried to use sets first but I received the same result